# Find dates by Time difference in list

Tags: r

I'm stuck with a function in R. I have a vector of dates, and i'm looking for couples of dates wich are spaced by more than 5 days.

Here is a part of my vector:

```
    [1] "2011-10-06" "2011-09-28" "2011-09-20" "2011-08-29" "2011-09-09" "2011-08-16"
    [7] "2011-08-05" "2011-07-28" "2011-07-18" "2011-07-06" "2011-06-27" "2011-06-17"
    [13] "2011-06-03" "2011-05-22" "2011-05-02" "2011-05-12" "2011-04-21" "2011-04-11"
    [19] "2011-04-01" "2011-03-23
```

I know how to compute time difference in my vector like this:

```
dates <- as.list( c( "2011-10-06","2011-09-28","2011-09-20","2011-08-29","2011-09-09","2011-08-16","2011-08-05","2011-07-28","2011-07-18","2011-07-06","2011-06-27","2011-06-17","2011-06-03","2011-05-22","2011-05-02","2011-05-12","2011-04-21","2011-04-11","2011-04-01","2011-03-23" ) )
diff( as.Date( unlist(dates) ) )
#Time differences in days
# [1]  -8  -8 -22  11 -24 -11  -8 -10 -12  -9 -10 -14 -12 -20  10 -21 -10 -10  -9
```

What i want is to return the couples of dates which fill this criteria. By example here the couple "2011-08-29","2011-09-09" is the first couple satisfaying the criteria "time difference > 5 days" in my vector.

Is there a way to return the couples which were computed ? Maybe using the number of items in the vector?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `which` on a test of your diff vector to get the locations, and use this to pick the values from your original data:

```
sel <- which(diff( as.Date( unlist(dates) ) )>5)

cbind(dates[sel],dates[sel+1])
     [,1]         [,2]        
[1,] "2011-08-29" "2011-09-09"
[2,] "2011-05-02" "2011-05-12"
```

Comment: Thanks! Its working well! It sure is handy! I had to use cbind.data.frame to conserve the date format. BTW, how could I set a new criteria in this formula ? I also need to filter all the time differences superior  to 150, but however i try, i cant set two criteria in same time.

Comment: Why would you need to set 2 criteria? >150 is also >5. In any case you just need to modify the logical statement within the `which` to meet you selection criteria, most likely using `&` to combine the 2 criteria.

Comment: Yeah, i made a mistake, i meant >5 and <150. It's working now. Thank you!